# ios7 UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes crashes app

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I wanted to set a consistent title colors for all my navigation bars:

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSFontAttributeName: MY_FONT_HERE};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes];
```

This piece of code work in iOS6 but CRASH in ios7.

The crash message is bizarre:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-                 [__NSCFConstantString pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107c34'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that MY_FONT_HERE is a string value, when it should be a UIFont. Instead of passing in the string to the attributes, initialize the font with `[UIFont fontWithName:MY_FONT_HERE]`.