# iOS 7 crash, iOS 6 OK - UINavigationBar: -[UILabel setTitleTextAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

I have an app that I was working on a long time ago and never completed. Recently started working on it again and I have run into a problem.

On **iOS 6** this code works fine:

```objc
UINavigationBar *modalNavBar = [editView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];
[modalNavBar setTitleTextAttributes:dict];
```

but on **iOS 7** it crashes and gives the following error:

> -[UILabel setTitleTextAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The method is clearly recognized since it comes up in the list of methods available on the **UINavigationBar** object.

I have read something about using **NSForegroundColorAttributeName** instead of **UITextAttributeTextColor** but that does not solve the problem on **iOS 7**, and on **iOS 6** it results in the color not being applied.

Any suggestions on a solution to this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036240/ios7-uinavigationbar-settitletextattributes-crashes-app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is a difference in how subviews are ordered in iOS7 and iOS6? I notice the error says that UILabel doesn't have the selector setTitleTextAttributes:, and indeed it does not. But your code indicates that you are expecting the object to be a UINavigationBar... but apparently it is a UILabel instead. So...

```
UINavigationBar *modalNavBar = [editView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

...is returning the wrong type of object. For some reason you've got a UILabel at index 0 when you run on iOS7, but a UINavigationBar at that index when you run on iOS6.

Comment: Ahhh! Hindsight is 20/20. I made a change to iterate over the subviews until I find a UINavigationBar and use that one and it works.

Comment: I iterate over controller.view.subviews to find a UITabBarCustomizeView, and then iterate over that to find a UINavigationBar. Works for iOS 6, but not for iOS 7, but at least it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the navigation bar using a documented property. For example, `navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;`. While one release of iOS may place the navigation bar at index 0 of the subviews array, another may add another view such that the navigationBar is no longer at that index.

Comment: Good idea. Now to figure out what I should be using in - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers.

Comment: Neither controller.navigationController.navigationBar nor controller.moreNavigationController.navigationBar is correct, so I think I need to iterate over the subviews until I find a UINavigationBar, which does work.